# wiringPi and crosstool-ng

Tags: cross-compilation, wiringpi

I have a Problem using `wiringPi` with `crosstool-ng`.
First I got this Error:

> libwiringPi.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

I think the problem might be that `./build` will not use crosstool-ng to build `wiringPi`?
I also tried to change the makefile:

```
CC = arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc
#CC =gcc
```

Then, while building `wiringPi` I got this error:

> make: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found

If I type the command right into the terminal, the command works.
Any other suggestions how to make `wiringPi` work with `crosstool-ng`?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my Notebook and Raspbian on the Pi.

For installing I followed these tutorials:

[Crosstool-NG](http://mac-opencv-projects.blogspot.de/2014/03/how-to-build-cross-compiler-for.html)

[WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at my project [Nard SDK](http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/) where I do what you require, crosstool-ng builds wiringPi. You could compare my file *nard/apps/wiringpi-lib/Makefile* with your *Makefile*.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the compiler in wiringPi's make file didn't work for me then I changed compiler name in gpio , wiringPiD, wiringPi ,devLib folder's makefiles .I also faced issue compiler of not finding header "wiringPi.h", then include path is modified to

```
     INCLUDE = -I$(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/include
```

in respective folder's make file.

```
    CC = /path/ to / compiler/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

Probably trying giving complete path of compiler. I used this repo https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools for raspian cross compiler tools.

In addition I faced issue that linker was unable to find wiringPi and wiringPiD libraries , so I added following in gpio/Makefile . Now, running "./build " gave me a dynamic library which is crosscompiled.

```
       LDFLAGS = -L$(DESTDIR)/lib
```